# Redirecting in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry for the nub question. I GTSed this like crazy but came up empty. I'm trying to redirect my page to a draft page but I have no idea what syntax to use. This is where I'm trying to redirect to:

```
"/stories/:id/draft"
```

My routes:

```
# Stories Routes
resources :stories
delete "/stories", to: "stories#destroy"
get "/stories/:id/draft", to: "stories#draft"
```

This is what I have so far. I don't know how to add the /draft part

```
redirect_to story_path(story.id)
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you show your routes.rb file?

Comment: you probably want to look at `rake routes | grep story`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I like to do this is

```
  match "/stories/:id/draft" => "stories#draft", :as => :stories_draft, via: :all # stories_draft(story.id)
```

Comment: This did it. I just had to add _path and boom, I got redirected there. Thanks a lot @MZaragoza

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your route like this named route:

```
get "/stories/:id/draft", to: "stories#draft", as: :stories_draft
```

which will provide you with this:

```
stories_draft GET    /stories/:id/draft(.:format) stories#draft
```

So, then you can call:

```
redirect_to stories_draft_path(story)
```

or,

```
redirect_to stories_draft_path(story.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help KM.